# using PhotoShop.dll in c#

Tags: c#

I have to work with .psd files. I have added all required PaintDotNet dlls. Also I have added reference to Photoshop.dll. But it is showing error that

> The type or namespace name 'PhotoShop' could not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

And here is my code:

```
using Photoshop;

string[] psds = Directory.GetFiles(@"Path_here", "*.psd", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var psd in psds)
{
    var psdFile = new PsdFile();
    psdFile.Load(psd); // Loading the psd file

    // Printing the file name and the file dimensions (width/height)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}x{2}",
            Path.GetFileName(psd),
            psdFile.ColumnCount,
            psdFile.RowCount);
}
```

Am unable to catch it up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the namespace is `Photoshop`?  Double click the reference in your Solution Explorer to open the Object Explorer.  That will show you the structure of the DLL

Comment: Pretty sure the namespace for that is: PhotoshopFile rather than just photoshop.

Comment: let me edit my words, using PhotoshopFile, this gets fixed, but a new exception thrown "Could not load file or assembly 'PaintDotNet.SystemLayer.Native.x64' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." Is this psd plugin not works for 32bit systems?

Comment: @Faiza what is the targer framework for your project?